# Swift converting String to NSDate returns nil

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm fighting with String to NSDate conversion in Swift.
I hope someone could help me with it.

my code:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
formatter.formatterBehavior = .BehaviorDefault

let tripDate = formatter.dateFromString(updatedAt)
```

Variable `updatedAt` is `"2015-11-11 15:43:18"`

After execution `tripDate` is `nil`.

What could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You was right. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `HH` instead of `hh`.

`hh` is for the 12h system with AM and PM, `HH` is for the 24h system.

Example:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: @Andrey please accept above answer, if this helps you.